# How to calculate the angle between a place on Earth and the Sun?

Tags: java, algorithm

For my application I need to calculate an angle between two different lines:

1) The first line is between a point on the earth which is defined by longitude and latitude and the center of the sun.

2) The second line is between a point on the earth which is defined by longitude and latitude and the surface on the moon with the smalles distance from the earth.

I have no idea how I should start there. Any hints?

Comment: Well, a little basic information: http://www.physicalgeography.net/fundamentals/6h.html

Comment: What is the angle between two points, please?

Comment: I think Java comes last in this case.

Comment: Sorry I confused it in my question. The angle bewteen the two path.

Comment: Your definitions of angles are a little confusing. In the first you define a line (point on earth and center of sun) but not what the other line is that makes up the angle. Similarly in the second (though of note I believe that if you assume the moon to be spherical then a line to the center of the moon will always pass through the closest point of the surface of the moon - this may make things easier).

Comment: @adarshr this is not my ordering ;)

Comment: @Chris yes I saw the problem, I unfortunately confused it in my question. I want to calculate the angle between line 1) and 2)

Comment: I assume you have the exact time as an input into this? Time of day will have an effect and of course more importantly time of month will. That having been said lunar orbits are quite complicated things from what I recall from last time I looked into it.

Comment: Date is going to be important here as all three objects are moving.  This is really a Mathematics question, not a Java question.

Comment: This should be moved to Math (http://math.stackexchange.com/) or Physics (http://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: There are practical programming issues here. Maybe there's a library that does this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you've actually got all three points of interest calculated already[*], where `O` is the position of the observer (on Earth), `S` is the position of the Sun and `M` is the point on the Moon, then:

```
OM . OS = |OM| * |OS| * cos(theta)
```

Or, in other words, to calculate `theta`, take the dot product of the two vectors, divide that result by the *magnitude* of those two vectors, and then take the inverse cosine of the result.

[*] your question only asks for the angle between two lines - if instead you want to know how to calculate the actual lines for any moment in time then you should rewrite your question.

Comment: Out of interest do common libraries (thinkign the standard ones rather than third party) do dot products or do you need to do the maths for that yourself? I've never had to try myself...

Comment: it's common in math libraries, but it's trivial anyway.  If you've two 3D vectors A and B it's just `(Ax * Bx) + (Ay * By) + (Az * Bz)`

Comment: Thanks but on of the problem is to get the position of the Sun and the Moon.

Comment: with 7k rep you should know how to write an accurate question by now...  suggest you modify this one to become a question about angle between two arbitrary vectors, and then write a new one asking how to calculate the solar and lunar positions.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, the questions is at what point in time. Moon revolves around the earth which in turn revolves around the sun so the distances and angles you mention are different at different point in time.

For example when you have an eclipse the angle is close to zero.

So without the information of time and exact knowledge of earths, moons and suns position at that given time the calculation is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to dig through the sources of [Celestia](http://www.shatters.net/celestia/) to look for equations that would let you determine the position of the point on the earth in relation to center of the moon and sun.

When you have those coordinates apply Alnitak's suggestion on vector [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_interpretation)s

Answer (score 1):

As a related answer to this problem. Did you know Wolframalpha.com can solve that problem?

For example, if you are looking:

- [`Sun altitude 9 pm at New York`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sun+altitude+9+pm+at+New+York)
- [`Sun  altitude  4:00 pm 12.12.2012 at Tallinn, Harju`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sun++altitude++4:00+pm+12.12.2012+at+Tallinn,+Harju)

You can do same with Mathematica kernel, and call in Java.

Comment: Or even better "angle between sun and moon 9 pm at New York". Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest following: transform all coordinates into one unique coordinate system (e.g. the sun and moon position in longitude/latitude of the earth-bound points). Then you can calculate the angle in that coordinate system easily.

Comment: I'd suggest that you try to imagine doing it without this step. :P